# How to render into 60fps video without lagging in power point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I do make a simple video like WatchData video by using Powerpoint. The problem that I occurs is that the video that I render is lagging even in 60fps. There are two ways I do render Powerpoint;

1. Just Export to Video. I do find that if you Export to Video in 4k, it will automatically convert into 60 fps
2. I do use macros and here is the code that I do (I do found this code in Youtube)

^

```
Sub PowerPointVideo() If ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus <> ppMediaTaskStatusInProgress Then ActivePresentation.CreateVideo FileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Your PowerPoint Video.wmv", _ UseTimingsAndNarrations:=True, _ VertResolution:=2160, _ FramesPerSecond:=60, _ Quality:=100 Else: MsgBox "There is another conversion to video in progress" End If End Sub
```

The problem is that, both method created lagging video. I do know the other way is to use Adobe After Effects but right now I want to stick into Powerpoint. So, how to fix it?

Comment: I only have exported a couple of videos at 60fps using a script, but I can not find it.

But in theory, there should not be any lagging, because the script will render 1 frame after it renders the last one. Are you sure it is not another thing? Maybe the video is not compressed?

Comment: @Rafael , yes. I do find that the exported video is not namely lag but not "smooth". Here is the video that I generated and I think that it is not as smooth as the WatchData video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE7ztfWluBY&ab_channel=%231

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video is off-topic on GDSE.  Perhaps try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in the video example, I noticed something very specific. Around the second 30, you have a simple panning of the elements. Elements moving right to left, without acceleration at a constant speed.

Let me explore to see if I am right.

If you are moving one element 100 pixels to the left, and you have 100 frames to move it, you can redraw the element 1 pixel each frame.

If you want to move it in multiples, either of time or pixels, you can move the element to 2 pixels per frame or use two frames per pixel.

But what I think you have is an interpolation or motion blur problem. PowerPoint draws full pixels. It does not draw smoothed pixels over time. Either it draws it or not. A smoothed pixel on movement would have some kind of motion blur. A semi-transparent pixel is getting more solid when the element is in an exact position and then semitransparent until it reaches the next pixel.

As the movement is slow, it is drawing pixels on a pattern, let's say 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2.

---

I would try to export the video at a higher resolution and resample it to see if you can get some smoothing between the pixels because of the additional spacing, (but probably it will only expand the pattern)

Or export at 60 FPS but extend the presentation time 3 times, so it gets extra slow, and then pass it thru a  video editing program so the extra frames are used to make a fake motion blur.

Look for tutorials for Davinci Resolve, which is free.

There are also programs to smooth time-lapses or hyper-lapses, one is Flowframes. It is not perfect but try it and see if it helps you smooth it.